# jQuery Infinite-scroll load content on same page (non-remote)

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I use this jQuery plugin:
https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

I currently use this:

```
$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector     : "#next:last",
    nextSelector    : "a#next:last",
    itemSelector    : ".veilingblok",
    path: function(index) {
        return "index2.html";
    }
});
```

All works great, great plugin, but, i use a remote page for the extra content.

Is there a way to scroll data on the page that is already there but hidden? For example: I want to load a total of 50 divs. If the user opens the page, 10 divs will show and 40 will be hidden. When he scrolls to the bottom of the page another 10 of those 40 hidden divs shows up.

So i dont want to use a remote file to load the new divs. Is that possible?

Hope someone can push me in the right direction. Thanks.